# Cookie value coming as empty in request

Tags: spring-boot

In a Spring Boot microservice architecture, I am facing an issue with cookie accessibility.

When cookies are set by the security service, they can be accessed both in the cloud gateway and the security service itself.

if the cookies are set by the cloud gateway, I can retrieve their values within the gateway, but they are not accessible in the security service getting the cookie name but not the value

Comment: If cookies are set in HTTP response using Set-Cookie headers, then these are saved in client and sent in subsequent requests to same origin domain as per attributes viz. secure, httpOnly, samesite, path. When Cloud gateway is setting cookie, one or more of these cookie attributes should be different from those when set by security service. Please check these cookie attributes first in your HTTP response in client.